# How do I programmatically input after a prompt with bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to run a bash script `bash.sh` that starts up a command line tool.

That command line tool has a prompt that says `Please enter your email:`

I then need a way to programmatically enter my email after the prompt.

I have tried simply `myemail@email.com` and I have tried `echo myemail@email.com`. Neither seem to work because the prompt does not allow me to run any more commands.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to stdin:

```
command_line_tool <<< "my@email.com"
```

Further reading:

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks! @hek2mgl